# Jquery .find() - restrictions for where to find

Tags: jquery, find, selector, restriction

I am using the .find() to find specifiek elements in a div.
Now what the .find() does do, is finding every element in that div. I want it only to find it in the first dimension, this means it should not search in div shilds. 
Now i know there might be a way with :not() as it uses normal selectors.

However, I dont think the .not() is connected with .find(). It doesn't adjust the search function of .find() it only adjusts the selector in the .find() element.

For example:

```
<div class="content">
  <ul>
     <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_1" value="yes"></li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_1" value="no"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
     <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_2" value="yes"></li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_2" value="no"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
     <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_2" value="yes"></li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_2" value="no"></li>
  </ul>

   <div class="subcontent" style="displaye: none;">
     <ul>
         <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_1_1" value="yes"></li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_1_1" value="no"></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
         <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_2_1" value="yes"></li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_2_1" value="no"></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
         <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_3_1" value="yes"></li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="radiobutton_3_1" value="no"></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

In this example in want to search for all radiobuttons, however i dont want to search in the div subcontent.

I've also tryed to check separately if the parrent div is :visible, for some odd reason this didn't work properly. So that's why i'm asking for this.

Hope someone could help me, thanks in advance!

 - Nkmol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".content").find(" > ul > li > input[type=radio]");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb2pY/

Answer (score 0):

try `$(div).find(>ul input:radio)`

Comment: I've tryed this, but it will still search for the radio's in the subcontent :( btw, i'm using "this" to make it more dynamic.


I've tested whith alert($(this).attr("class")); that it does select the right div's. In this case the alert would give "content".

Comment: oh got it $(div#content).find(>ul input:radio)
is this works for you ?

Comment: sadly not.
It indeed should work with this, but it still manage to select the other input:radio in the subcontent.
I tested the selection with $(this).css('background', 'red');

Strange is that the subdivs aren't selected(I do tell which div he should select), only the inputs in the subdiv :S